# How to use MSBuild engine in Monodevelop on Linux for a VB.NET project

Tags: linux, vb.net, msbuild, monodevelop

When I try to build a hello-world VB.NET project with MSBuild enabled in Monodevelop I get this error.

```
'Error: Target named 'Build' not found in the project. (HelloWorld)'
```

The project will build when the MSBuild feature is disabled. I don't really know what I'm doing, but I'm trying to set myself up so I can start writing .NET applications. I'm not entirely sure I need this feature, so maybe someone can enlighten me as to what MSBuild is used for. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a VB.NET project? If not do you have the msbuild package installed?

Comment: Yes it is, and yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so there are a few MonoDevelop bugs here due to support for VB.NET not being as good as the C# support.

First MonoDevelop does not add the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />` to the .vbproj file.

This is filed as [bug 554445](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55445)

If you add this import to the .vbproj the error about the missing 'Build' targets should be fixed. However then you will probably run into the next problem.

Mono's MSBuild then tries to use vbnc.exe which does not seem to currently be shipped with Mono.

If you try to use the vbc.exe instead by setting the VbToolExe to be vbc.exe in the project:

```
<VbcToolExe>vbnc.exe</VbcToolExe>
```

You then run into another exception.

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicCommandLineParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000286 (from typeref, class/assembly Roslyn.Utilities.IObjectReadable, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)`

There is another bug logged for this but it is a private bug so you cannot see it.

So currently VB.NET projects do not compile with MSBuild so you will either need to use xbuild or the default built-in support for using vbc.exe in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Do you know what the current state of things are when vbnc is installed and is used as the compiler after inserting that line into the .vbproj file? I just get this error "Error: Compiler crashed with code: 1. (HelloWorld)".

Comment: One more thing, how do you enable xbuild in monodevelop 5.1?

Comment: So there are two options both confusing refer to MSBuild. The one in global preferences - Projects - Build - 'Build with MSBuild instead of xbuild' enables MSBuild. If that is unchecked then going into the project options - Build - General and check 'Use MSBuild engine' will use xbuild. Unchecking this will go back to using the VB compiler directly without xbuild or MSBuild. There seem to be some problems using xbuild here too - it does not like the parameters passed to the compiler when building debug. Release seems to work.